# Invalid Keystore Format in React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I build the bundleRelease from a system from which the keystore was made, Now I am using another system to build the android bundleRelease but I am facing invalid keystore format for the same keystore. I tried making a new one but playstore is not accepting the app this time.

Comment: what is "another system"?

Comment: If app submitted already using your old keystore then next time app should be signed using same keystore to submit on playstore.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies but teh keystore is not able o find the path

Comment: Then add the error you are facing in question it will help people here to understand problem